# @font-face Helvetica Neue Ultra Light

Tags: css

I am using this code

```
@font-face {
 font-family:myHelveticaUltraLight;
 src: local("Helvetica Neue UltraLight"),
      local("myHelveticaUltraLight"),
      url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueUltraLight.ttf'),
      url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueUltraLight.eot') format("opentype"); /* IE */
}
```

to provide Helvetica Neue Ultra Light to users of my website. It works ok with Safari on my Mac, but when I tested it in Chrome or Firefox on Windows it doesn't show that font (it's very thick). Any idea what could be the problem and how to fix it please? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried setting the font-weight? ie font-weight:300

Comment: edit: the second local is supposed to be local("HelveticaNeue-UltraLight"). It still doesnt work tho.

Comment: Yes, I tried font-weight:100 and nothing's changed.

Comment: Maybe? http://caniuse.com/fontface and http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: Try converting it using fontsquirrel and implementing it that way http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Comment: Are you sure that it is actually finding the font? If you have the font installed on your Mac, then it will show even if the path is incorrect.

Comment: NOTE: Helvetica Neue is a highly professional non-free font, usually you are not allowed to use it on websites unless you paid for.

Answer (score 2):

Contact the copyright holder for information on using Helvetica Neue on web pages.

Answer (score 1):

I've used helvetica neue light using following example

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helveticaneuelight';
    src: url('http://snippethosted.googlecode.com/svn/helveticaneue-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://snippethosted.googlecode.com/svn/helveticaneue-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://snippethosted.googlecode.com/svn/helveticaneue-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://snippethosted.googlecode.com/svn/helveticaneue-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://snippethosted.googlecode.com/svn/helveticaneue-light-webfont.svg#helveticaneuelight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no SVG format... That is webkits first choice in font format.
Here is my EMERGENCY "don't know what's up with this font in webkit" kit. These are the issues that sometimes plague webkit on Windows fonts.

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

 -webkit-perspective: 1000;

font-smooth: always;

-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
// or -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
//  or adding a textshadow helps also sometimes:
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

Also adding a faux bold looks terrible most often. The font must be a bold font in webkit for some font types.